# Custom flutter widget shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm attempting to build the following layout in Flutter.

I'm looking to achieve 2 things:

- Render a background that draws a diagonal side (I'm guessing through a BoxDecoration)
- Have the pink container clip children along the diagonal side - i.e. if the text is too large for one line it should wrap to a new line.

Any ideas?

[image: Diagonal layout shape]

Answer (score 7):

Here is my code:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Pic(),
    Info(),
  ],
)
```

For widget Pic:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      image: NetworkImage(
          'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2014/02/Facebook-Campaign-Article-Main-Image2.png'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

For widget Info:

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: TrapeziumClipper(),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3/5,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 6/15
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Testing clipping with soft wrap',
            softWrap: true,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

For TrapeziumClipper:

```
class TrapeziumClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width * 2/3, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TrapeziumClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways you could do this. One would be to use a CustomPainter to use it as the background and have it draw the pink + picture.

Another way would be to use a stack, something like this:

```
container (with pink background)
  -> stack
     -> picture, clipped
     -> text, etc
```

You'd lay out the text however you normally would, and you'd align the picture to the right and define a [ClipPath](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) that clipped it as you want it.

To make the text wrap, put it within a [ConstrainedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html) or [SizedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) and make sure it's set to wrap (softwrap property I believe).