# Align items diagonally within it's parent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a widget that is made out of 2 different components:

- image
- container with text

I could just make a vertical split between the image but my aim is to have the split diagonal with diagonal text align aswell (or that the items would align themselves with the diagonal).

[image]

I was able to achieve most of the part with this resource: [Custom flutter widget shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641287/custom-flutter-widget-shape), but I am having problems with aligning text diagonally with the parent line. It is shown like this

[image: the text is aligned vertically and ignores the parent widget]

This is my code for now

```
     Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2014/02/Facebook-Campaign-Article-Main-Image2.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: TrapeziumClipper(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('1'),
                  Text('2'),
                  Text('3'),
                  Text('4'),
                  Text('5'),
                  Text('6'),
                ],
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

And this is my clipper line draw.

```
 class TrapeziumClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 53 / 100, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 1 / 3, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TrapeziumClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after trying out with CustomMultiChildLayout and much more other widgets I have come to the conclusion that there is really not any way around other than to have comlpicated "hacks". 
The one simpeples for me was this:

```
Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: (mediaQuery.size.width * 53 / 100) - mediaQuery.size.width * 0.14,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              height: 15,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    '23. feb 2020',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: AppColors.lightGrey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '21.00',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: AppColors.lightGrey,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: (mediaQuery.size.width * 57 / 100) - mediaQuery.size.width * 0.14,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              height: 20,
              child: FittedBox(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                child: Text(
                  'item title name',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: AppColors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: (mediaQuery.size.width * 61 / 100) - mediaQuery.size.width * 0.14,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              height: 15,
              child: Text(
                'address',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 11,
                  fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: AppColors.lightGrey,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Container(
              width: (mediaQuery.size.width * 3.7 / 5) - mediaQuery.size.width * 0.14,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              height: 32,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'GOING',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: AppColors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          AppIcons.guests,
                          size: 15,
                          color: AppColors.white,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '24',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Red Hat Text',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: AppColors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Basically what I did was get the screensizes of the elements and then by simply testing, I calculated how much width can Container() take in order to stay in the trapezoid area. The only thing I am concerned about is the responsivness with larger/smaller devices, but I hope that it will work since it's based on mediaquery sizes and not fixed ones.